# Call a function on click pugjs

Tags: pug

I want to make a reversal to img when clicking img as pugjs code
This is my javascript code

```
<div class="cards" id="cards" data-status="off">
    <img class="" src="assets/img/plus.png" alt="">
</div>
<script>
    var cards= document.getElementById("cards");
    cards.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var toggleStatus = cards.dataset.status;
        switch (toggleStatus) {
            case "on":
                 cards.dataset.status = "off";
                 // change plus img to minus img
                 break;
            case "off":
                 cards.dataset.status = "on";
                 // change minus img to plus img
                 break;
         }
     }, false);
</script>
```

but I want to make this as pugjs code.
I am new to pugjs.
This is my pugjs code, but it's wrong.

```
.cards#cards(data-status="off" onclick="viewAll()")
- var dataStatus = true;
    script.
        function viewAll() {
           if (dataStatus) {
                dataStatus = false;
           } else {
                dataStatus = true;
           }
        }
    if dataStatus
        img(src="assets/images/plus.png" alt="")
    else
        img(src="assets/images/minus.png" alt="")
```

Anybody, can you help me?

Comment: Pug is compiled into static HTML by the server before it is sent to a browser. You can't use Pug conditionals to change elements on the page after it's been sent to the browser.

Comment: Thanks, @Sean. So you mean is it is impossible? if it is, how can reversal IMG or text when clicking the button? Thanks for your time.

Comment: That would need to be done exclusively in client-side javascript—not Pug.

Answer (score 0):

This conditional cannot be done using PugJs alone, the general rendering process is very simple!

It just compiles the source code into a Js function that will return a rendered HTML string with your data.

You can do this, but you will need to dynamically render that content, you can do this using Node.js and creating a function that can be reused and called with different data sets.